# Anchor tab for differen pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set anchor to jump on other page with specified heading but my anchor tab is not working.
I have two files index.html and anti foam.html to link with each other but my anchor is unable to jump the Pulp and Paper Industry on other page.

### index.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 gallery-item-wrapper nature outside">
                <div class="gallery-item">
                    <div class="gallery-thumb">
                        <img src="img/works/im2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="2nd gallery Thumb">
                        <div class="image-overlay"></div>
                        <a href="img/works/im2.png" class="gallery-zoom"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery-details">
                      <div class="editContent">
                          <h5><a href="antifoam.html#Pulp and Paper Industry.">Pulp and Paper Industry.</a></h5> 
                      </div>
                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

### antifoam.html is the file to be linked.

```
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card" style="width:100%">
            <img class="card-img-top cimage" src="img/antifoam/PPI.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
           <h3>Pulp and Paper Industry.</h3>
           <p class="cp">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Please tell me where am I doing mistake to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to anchor at the ID. So you could have the index page link be:

`<h5><a href="antifoam.html#pulp">Pulp and Paper Industry.</a></h5>`

and the anchor be:

```
 <h3 id="pulp" >Pulp and Paper Industry.</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a “landing” `<a>` tag with `id` (*e.g.* `pulp-and-paper-industry`) in your target page (`antifoam.html`):

```
<h3>
  <a id="pulp-and-paper-industry">Pulp and Paper Industry.</a>
</h3>
```

Then you can link it in your source page through `href`:

```
<h5>
  <a href="antifoam.html#pulp-and-paper-industry">Pulp and Paper Industry.</a>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do it like this:

`<a href="pagename.html#just%20an%20example"></a> <a id="just an example"></a>`

I hope you can do something with this. Maybe dont use the %20 and make it a one word instead. Just trail and error

Beldr